# antique/rare math books to sell/donate (not to university)

Tags: books

I'm looking for resources for selling and/or donating my father's antique/rare mathematics books.  He was a math professor for many years and has an extensive book collection (math, physics, photographic).  He is now retired and needs to downsize his extensive collection. The universities in our area (Boston) and AIM are not taking book donations at this time so we are looking for other options.

Comment: Also, https://help.archive.org/help/how-do-i-make-a-physical-donation-to-the-internet-archive/

Comment: @Darij, "also"? I think you didn't read the first page carefully enough...

Comment: Hi, I buy / collect old math books, especially from number theory and algebra. Do you happen to have a list of the books? Feel free to contact me directly.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Good point; that answer should probably be the top one!

Comment: @Marcus, Can you email me your contact information and your location so I can send you a list?  Im located in Boston area.   smitheps@gmail.com